# Safe ObjectInputStream.readObject from untrusted source

Tags: java, serialization

I want to sent a significant number of Java objects over the Internet from client to server. Simple text base solutions (like json or xml) will not work due to the amount of data transferred. Even compression would take too long. I really need to exploit sharing present in the objects.

Of course I would prefer not to implement a complete serialization implementation myself.

One possible solution would be to use Object serialization in Java. As I cannot completely trust the client this poses a problem as a rogue client could instantiate some weird objects on the server.

A possible solution would be to override ObjectInputStream.resolveClass. As I will only be transmitting objects from a limited set of classes I can easily check if the class being resolved belongs to that limited set.

Can you guys poke holes in this idea? Have you done something similar yourself?

Comment: "Even compression would take too long"... how do you know?  Have you measured it?

Comment: The server can only deserialize objects that it has in its classpath. If a client sends an arbitrary rogue object to the server, the server won't be able to deserialize it. I think you base your design choices on false, or unverified assumptions.

Comment: There is a huge amount of sharing in the data. Back-of-the-envelope calculations show that first flattening it (for instance to JSon) and then compressing it would not be possible as the intermediate data would be gigantic. Preservation of sharing is a must.

Comment: I do not want to grant the client the privilege to freely deserialize anything in the server classpath. For instance, it could deserialize a complete new tomcat instance or some other monstrosity. At the very least this would create a very easy denial of service attack vector.